# Are solid-state windmills feasible?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, drag

Imagine a structure exposed to wind.  It is designed chemically so that a molecule striking the surface can transfer kinetic energy to electrons that are promoted to a higher energy state.  These move through a conduction band and are collected as in a solar cell.  Maybe a layered structure akin to graphite cut diagonally would be helpful to orient the interaction and transmit current.

Has anyone studied such a "wind panel"?  The energy density from wind friction is likely to be lower than that of solar energy, but could the energy threshold be used to slow wind to a desired velocity?

Comment: This is very similar to a solid state microphone, right?

Comment: What energy  does an air molecule carry if you take wind velocities between 10 an 30 m/s. compare it to the energy needed to ionize an atom. or compare it to the energy of a photon of visible light. Than you find your answer easily.

Comment: This seems like calculating the energy for a windmill in general, but let's see: 1/2 (28 g/mol) (30 m/s)^2 = 12.6 J/mol.  A mole is around 23 L (depending on weather) so that's 0.47 J/L. What's less clear is how to get from a surface to the number of liters!  The molecule per se doesn't need to reach the surface - it can collide elastically with another that previously spent its energy.  Turbulence applies. Serious physics, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The question @trula asked wasn't about the energy of a windmill in general. The question was about a single molecule. The distinction is very important.

It's kind of like ionizing vs non-ionizing radiation. You can blast a piece of semiconductor with as much radio wave radiation as you like, but the radio waves won't free a single electron (short of simply heating the semiconductor). However, if you apply even a small amount of x-rays radiation, you'll start to free electrons.

Why? Because electromagnetic radiation is quantized. A radio wave photon does not have the energy to free an electron, so it doesn't matter how many you apply. In contrast, an x-ray photon has the energy to free an electron, so even a single x-ray photon can free an electron.

Air is likewise quantized. It's made out of discrete particles, so the question here isn't: How much energy is there in the air? The question is: How much energy is there in a single particle?

BTW, that's not to say that air moving past a structure can't free any charges, but I don't think it's by the mechanism you propose.

Comment: Well, if I write out the mol as 6.02E+23 particles, that's 2.09E-23 J/particle.  Comparing to a photon by dividing by h = 6.63E+34 J s yields 3.15E+10/s, or 31 GHz, which is in the microwave range.  My first thought was that this could be plenty of energy since we don't need to ionize anything but simply want to promote a particle to a higher energy level in a semiconductor, but I do see we're vastly below the 2400 J/mol thermal energy (RT) so both levels would be almost equally occupied.  "It seems like there ought to be a way to do it..."

Comment: The band gap of silicon is about 1.1 eV (which is typical for a semiconductor), so about 2e-19 J. In other words, the energy you gave is about 4 orders of magnitude too small to do anything useful.